# Questions about React and creating timers when a component is created

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to create a component that hides itself after a few seconds. I have 2 questions:

1. Where should I place the `setTimeout`? Probably in the constructor, `componentWillMount`, or `componentDidMount`. Is there a differences in placing it in `componentWillMount` or `componentDidMount`?
2. Is it bad practice to do `this.state = ...` outside the constructor?

Here's what I have:

```
class Message extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.state = {
            closed: false,
            closeTimeout: null
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        if (this.props.closeAfter) {
            this.state.closeTimeout = setTimeout(_ => {
                this.setState({closed: true});
            }, this.props.closeAfter);
        }
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        if (this.state.closeTimeout) {
            clearTimeout(this.state.closeTimeout);
        }
    }

    render() {
        return ...
    }
};
```

Comment: Basically your assumptions are correct - and you want componentDidMount as that's after the component has been rendered the first time which is when you'd want to start the countdown.

Comment: in the samples, they put on the didmount. https://facebook.github.io/react/ I believe it is the best place to be, too.

Comment: And yes, you should not touch state directly outside of the constructor because React batches state updates. Always use `setState`.